# How can I import just one symbol from a package or fix weird LuaLaTeX anomaly?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, symbols, luatex, unicode

Most of the world uses `~` (U+007E - Tilde) or `∼` (U+223C - Tilde Operator) to denote similarity. In LaTeX we can use `\~{}` or `\sim`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}

$ABC$ \~{} $DEF$

$ABC\sim DEF$

\end{document}
```

However the Japanese Math Curriculum uses `∽` (U+223D - Reversed Tilde). There exists `\backsim` in `amssymb`, but the output looks slightly different from that in textbooks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}

$ABC\backsim DEF$

\end{document}
```

The `\similar` command from `jpnedumathsymbols` is exactly what I want but the package makes other unwanted changes. Also it did not work on LaTeX. Strangely, when I compiled the following on LuaLaTeX, the initial output was correct, but the engine was hanging with something similar to `generating font cache`. Once the engine finished, the symbol was gone. What??? It was my first time using that engine. Adding the lua option did not solve the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{jpnedumathsymbols}
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}

$ABC\similar DEF$

\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{jpnedumathsymbols}[lua]
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}

$ABC\similar DEF$

\end{document}
```

Can I import just the `\similar` command from `jpnedumathsymbols` to use in LaTeX? If not how can I repair LuaLaTeX or the backend component reponsible for the anomaly?

Comment: You can find the definition of `\similar` in [jpnedumathsymbols.sty](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/jpnedumathsymbols/jpnedumathsymbols.sty): `%% \similar
\let\originalsimilar\similar
\DeclareRobustCommand{\similar}[1][1.3]{\mathrel{\lower.2ex\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{∽}}}}`

Answer (score 6):

With lualatex you need a font which has the symbol. You can call `albatross U+223D` to get a list of fonts. E.g. latin modern math has it and so this here works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,amsmath}
\newfontface\latinmath{latinmodernmath}
\newcommand\similar{\mathrel{\text{\latinmath ^^^^223d}}}
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}

$ABC\similar DEF$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or use unicode-math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}

$ABC \backsim DEF$

\end{document}
```